# Any Issues installing STI Brake/Shifter levers to bike with direct-pull V-Cantilever brakes?

Tags: brakes

I want to install drop bars in my hybrid bike and also thinking of getting STI brake/shifter lever. The bike has V-Brakes. Is there any issues on doing this that I should be concerned about?

[image]

Comment: You mention direct pull and V in the description. it is typically one or the other but not both. Do you have a small "V" shaped (straddle) cable attached to the brake arms?

Comment: I thought so too but according to this website they are one and the same: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/canti-direct.html   this are the brakes i have.

Comment: I hope my edited answer will be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard V brakes do not work well with STI levers, they don't pull enough cable to allow the V brake to be setup properly; you end up with the pads so close to the rim that they are always rubbing on it or needing to be adjusted and the braking can also be poor.

I know of 2 options to get around this, you get a V brake Travel Adjuster or Travel Agent - essentially a pulley that increases the amount of cable that is pulled by the STI shifter or you get some 'Mini V Brakes' as these have a shorter arm and so work with the STI shifters.

Comment: Not exactly STI, but these levers http://gevenalle.com/product/cxv/ integrate friction shifters with "long pull" levers for MTB brakes. (I own these and like them a lot).  Of course, Travel Agents are way cheaper ($20 / wheel).

Answer (score 0):

Road brake levers are compatible with  some cantilever brakes. If your cantilevers use a straddle cable (a small cable that attaches to each arm then to the main brake cable) they will work. If you have a single cable that attaches to both arms then they are incompatible.

Comment: Are your sure?   OP is referring to a direct pull cantilever.

Comment: I have only heard of cantilever or direct pull being exclusive unique designs, it is one or the other but can't be both.. Not sure what  the OP means by direct pull V cantilever.

Comment: After some research I guess any brake that is mounted on a post that attaches to the fork is a cantilever. Locally we refer to the types as "direct pull" (aka as mountain bike), "V" brakes are cantilever that use a straddle wire.

Comment: Isn't terminology wonderful; where I am (in the UK) a V brake is a direct pull cantilever as shown here: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/canti-direct.html and a cantilever with a straddle wire is just a cantilever brake as shown here: http://sheldonbrown.com/canti-trad.html.